# Advanced power options for lid closing

Tags: 14.04, suspend, power-management, hibernate

I have ubuntu 14.04 installed on my dell e5440.
What I'm trying to do is to make my computer suspend when I close the lid when I'm plugged in and hibernate when on battery power.

What I've managed so far is to override the power settings to hibernate when I close the lid.

Suggestions?

Comment: Please do not add `[SOLVED]` to the title. Marking an answer as accepted is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `gnome-tweak-tool` by:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Hit Super key/Windows key and search for `Tweak Tool`. Go to 'Power' options and change the behavior as you wish.

[image]

Comment: This is is for gnome exclusively or does this cover Unity as well?

Comment: It suspends the computer although I told it to hibernate on battery power, do I need to do something more?
I looked into the power options and it is blank for the spot of close lid on battery